# Send text from my watch app

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I know you can send text messages from the watch messages app but can I send a text from my own watch app similar to how an iPhone app can send a link or image to the message app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no API to do this in WatchKit; the closest you can get is using Handoff and prompting the user to open your app on their iPhone, which can then present an MFMessageComposeViewController with the appropriate content. If you’d like a watch-only solution, you should [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) for it.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the quick response!